# How to trigger / simulate barcode scan event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events, barcode-scanner

I'd like to solve a bug in our product, but I don't have any Zebra scanners at home. We use [Vue Barcode Scanner plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-barcode-scanner) for scanning barcodes.
What I know, a typical barcode scan looks like ~10 keystrokes with numbers then a TAB. So I tried to write a script like

```
"12345678900    ".split('').forEach(c => document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: c})))
```

Aaaaaand nope, this ain't triggering a scan event. Any different ideas, how to mock a scan event?

Comment: It may help to confirm the issue if you share how & with what options you've initialized the linked plugin.

Comment: This isn't necessarily related directly to your issue, but just a note from my experience with barcodes - some barcode fonts/languages expect an * on either side of the text in order to read the scan. e.g. `*12345678900*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you linked explicitly indicates in its latest iteration that listens specifically for the `keypress` event, not `keydown`. From the `README`:

> ### Update
>
> - ...
> - Listener for keypress instead of keydown (0.2)

> ### Methods
>
> #### init
>
> Init method use for add event listener (keypress) for the scanner.

I also confirmed this fact by perusing the source code:

- [`index.js:74`](https://github.com/noomerzx/vue-barcode-scanner/blob/1a68271d7e11568accfe4a6044342c07a3d53402/index.js#L74) explicitly adds an event listener on the `keypress` event.
- [`index.js:184-189`](https://github.com/noomerzx/vue-barcode-scanner/blob/1a68271d7e11568accfe4a6044342c07a3d53402/index.js#L184-L189) filters any `keydown` events that are not "control characters"